# Как в с++ предать функцию в функцию

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

У меня есть вот такая функция

```
Object* create_func(){
    Object1* temp;
    return temp;
}
```

и вот такая структура

```
struct SFactory
{
    const char *_ID;
    Object *(*_CreateFunc)();
    SFactory *_Next;
    static SFactory *_Head;

    static SFactory *Find(const char *id) noexcept;
    Object *Create(const char *id); // static
};
```

Как мне ее передать в конструктор структуры

```
static SFactory regB = {"Object1", (*create_func)()};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто по имени. Такой [пример](https://ideone.com/1gPN5g) устроит?

```
struct Object{};

Object* create_func()
{
    Object* temp;
    return temp;
}

struct SFactory
{
    const char *_ID;
    Object *(*_CreateFunc)();
};

static SFactory regB = {"Object1", create_func};
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало

Comment: Спасибо здесь принимает форму принятого ответа (птичка слева от вопроса).

Comment: std::fubction сюда бы....

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Из пушки по воробьям?...